# Chrome is really slow on mac

Tags: mac, google-chrome, performance, osx-yosemite

I have Yosemite, 16GB Ram. Chrome started to work really laggy. You can feel the lag while scrolling a basic google search page. Till now I tried:

- Disable all extensions for incognito mode. But even incognito mode was laggy.
- from chrome://flags I switched

  1. Enable GPU rasterization.
  2. Use GPU to rasterize web content.
  3. Disable hardware-accelerated video decode
  4. Disable support for Cast Streaming hardware video encoding

none helped. Then I installed Chrome-Beta over Chrome and it is still laggy. I checked fps from developer console its around 24 fps but you can feel the lag pretty easily.

Also GPU raster is off couldn't find a way to turn it on.

What could be the problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a solution for Chrome/Chromium/Chrome-Beta but I downloaded [Chrome Canary](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html) which seems to be working normal.

Comment: Is this still an issue? If you're comfortable with the dev console, the call flame graph could give you a good comparison. External process monitoring probably won't tell you much, but recording both might show a little more.